# Move from PHP 5.2 (mysql) to 7.3 (pdo): chars loaded from database dont display correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i move a website to php 7.3 and changed from old mysql to pdo. All works fine but the german characters dont display correctly. I have read here a lot but didnt find an answer.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `KategorieID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Bezeichnung` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Vorgänger` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`KategorieID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci
```

It is coded in latin1

This is my pdo database connection:

```
try{

        $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES latin1");
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.88;dbname=test;charset=latin1","testuser","testpass",$options);
}catch (PDOException $ex){
        die("Die Datenbank ist momentan nicht erreichbar.".$ex->getMessage());
}
```

It is also coded in latin1

This is the header of my website:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=latin1\" />"."\r\n";
```

It is coded in latin1 i also tried "ISO-8859-1"

There is how i read the data:

```
$str = "SELECT Bezeichnung, KategorieID, Vorgänger FROM test_table WHERE (Vorgänger=:vg) ORDER BY Bezeichnung";
$rs = $db->prepare($str);
$rs->bindValue(":vg",5);
$rs->execute();
$row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is part of the result that is shown on the website:

> J�germeister

But ist must be:

> Jägermeister

I checkd the entry with phpmyadmin. There it will be displayed correctly. If i run my old mysql code on php 5.2 i get the correct results. I did not set any charsets in db-connection there. Maybe i missed something in pdo?

Comment: What happens if you set it to UTF-8?

Comment: If i set $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES latin1"); to $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"); it works. why?

Comment: I’m not sure as to why it worked before, but I had the same problem and that fixed it for me too. 
According to this article, utf-8mb4 is the best option.  There’s some detailed explanation of the differences in this article:  https://medium.com/@manish_demblani/breaking-out-from-the-mysql-character-set-hell-24c6a306e1e5